# How to get root layout programmatically and set it as content view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have xml file as specified below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testapp.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If I want to take relativelayout(_main) and assign it to local relativelayout variable programmatically and then set it as contentview instead of setting as

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

I tried other way

```
main = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);
```

Still I got the error. What is way of getting it? My aim is to load the custom view to the current layout. How to do it?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if i understood correctly what are you trying to do here, but if you need to fetch root view programmatically and use it later you can do it like this:

```
RelativeLayout rlMain = (RelativeLayout) getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.main)
```

But as Nauman Afzaal said, you should inflate custom view, rather than add it the way you're trying now.

Answer (score 1):

> > My Aim is to load the custom view to the current layout .How to do it.

You should inflate your custom view to currently added view. You can define any relative layout in your main xml and then inflate your new view inside it.